# Django - onchange dropdown to display different forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a `form` consisting of 1 dropdown with the following possible values:

`cats
 dogs`

the field has`widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange':'form.submit();'})` And i would like to display a `CreateCatsForm` or a `CreateDogsForm` depending on the choice.

I've done some research and i guess i could do it using ajax, as in the example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) or is there any usual/`good practice` way of doing it?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking: there are many ways to do certain things. If ajax is acceptable for your business requirements then it’s probably the most user friendly. But submitting to the server and returning a different form depending on the input can also be acceptable if designed well. This is really a matter of UI.

Comment: @dirkgroten, I was wondering if there is a `django way` regarding this problem. For example, first i started using function based views but then i found out about the generic class based views and they seemed to reduce much of the hassle. I just wanted to know if there is a generic way of dealing with dynamic forms in django. Thx for your answer anyway:)

Comment: The problem you describe is a bit too vague to really answer this. If your cats and dogs forms are quite similar with a couple of differences you could just load one form and hide/unhide fields in the page using javascript. Django is very object-oriented nowadays with heavy use of generic classes and mixins so if you think that way, what’s common for cats and dogs and start from generic, you’re adhering to Django practices.

Comment: Mike, have you solved it yet? I have the same question, but seems a bit hard to find someone sharing an answer. If you solved it, can you pls share your solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442820/django-select-choose-a-specific-form-dynamically-from-a-drop-down-or-link-o